# Convert arrays to key value pair

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array

```
[
{"field" : "flight1", "value" : "123"},
{"field" : "flight2", "value" : "456"}
]
```

is it possible to become key value pair?

```
{
"flight1" : "123",
"flight2" : "456"
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` and return object as result.

```js
var arr = [{"field" : "flight1", "value" : "123"},{"field" : "flight2", "value" : "456"}]

var result = arr.reduce(function(r, e) {
  r[e.field] = e.value;
  return r;
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Please add some meaningful name to r & e, this does not really explain what it does. like : arr.reduce(function(recurring, value) {}

Comment: I think I prefer this shorthand which is a bit easier to logically follow: `Object.fromEntries(data.map(obj => [obj.field, obj.value]));`

Answer (score 3):

The `new Map()` constructor can do this for you:

```
var data = [
    {"field": "flight1", "value": "123"},
    {"field": "flight2", "value": "456"}
];
var result = new Map(data.map(obj => [obj.field, obj.value]));
```

If you're not familiar with `Map` objects, they work almost exactly the same as plain objects, except they are a little easier to iterate over, and have a `.size` property.

But if you prefer to have a plain object, you can get one this way:

```
var result = Object.fromEntries(data.map(obj => [obj.field, obj.value]));
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. I hope you don't mind that I expanded it to include an example of getting a plain object in a similar way.

Answer (score 2):

You could map the key value pair and assign it to an object.

```js
var data = [{ field: "flight1", value: "123" }, { field: "flight2", value: "456" }],
    result = Object.assign(...data.map(a => ({ [a.field]: a.value })));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: `map` returns an array of objects, not a single object. The OP wants `{a:1,b:2}`, not `[{a:1},{b:2}]`

Comment: Why not `Object.fromEntries()`? It's a little less complex than your example.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a standard `for` loop:-

```js
var data = [{"field" : "flight1", "value" : "123"},{"field" : "flight2", "value" : "456"}];

var obj = {};

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    obj[data[i].field] = data[i].value;

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone another day. I tried all the examples above, but each time the console was giving me something like this:
`{
  flight1: "123",
  flight2: "456"
}`

My problem was that I was converting a serialized array way to soon which resulted in lots of tiny problems. Below was the code that didn't work:

```
var data = $('#myform').serializeArray();
data = JSON.stringify(data);
data,result = Object.assign(...data.map(a => ({ [a.name]: a.value })));
database.addUser(result);
```

Note that flight1 and flight2 lost their double quotes. Below was my solution:

```
var data = $('#myform').serializeArray();
data,result = Object.assign(...data.map(a => ({ [a.name]: a.value }))); //result was already turned into a JSON array
database.addUser(result);
```

NB: This was a code for submitting user information to a database (neDB) using the electron framework