# Separate Array into multiple objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, javascript-objects

How to separate the Array to objects,

```
Need to convert the following
arr = [
    { name: 'abc', age: 15, roll_no: 25 },
    { name: 'def', age: 10, roll_no: 20 },
    { name: 'xyz', age: 16, roll_no: 18 },
  ];

Expected Output :

arr = [ abc : { name: 'abc', age: 15, roll_no: 25 },
        def : { name: 'def', age: 10, roll_no: 20 },
        xyz : { name: 'xyz', age: 16, roll_no: 18 }]
```

Kindly help me in this. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Does these answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43626156/how-to-convert-an-array-of-objects-to-object-with-key-value-pairs and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43779084/convert-arrays-to-key-value-pair

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Could you, please, provide what you've already tried ? It will be easier for us, to help you, if we know what you've already tried. In doubt, please refer to the [ask] section.

Comment: FYI, your "Expected Output" is invalid Javascript. Arrays cannot have keys. I believe what you intended to have is this instead: 
```
var arr = {
  "abc": {
    "name": "abc",
    "age": 15,
    "roll_no": 25
  },
  "def": {
    "name": "def",
    "age": 10,
    "roll_no": 20
  },
  "xyz": {
    "name": "xyz",
    "age": 16,
    "roll_no": 18
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

we can do this via `forEach` though not an efficient way

```js
arr = [
    { name: 'abc', age: 15, roll_no: 25 },
    { name: 'def', age: 10, roll_no: 20 },
    { name: 'xyz', age: 16, roll_no: 18 },
  ];

// empty object
const obj = {};

// Looping through & adding
arr.forEach(item => {
  obj[item.name] = item;
});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr.name] = curr;
  return acc;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `reduce` method to transform the array into an object with keys as the `name` property and values as the objects themselves.

```
const arr = [
  { name: 'abc', age: 15, roll_no: 25 },
  { name: 'def', age: 10, roll_no: 20 },
  { name: 'xyz', age: 16, roll_no: 18 },
];

const obj = arr.reduce((acc, item) => ({ ...acc, [item.name]: item }), {});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
arr.map(a=>{return {[a.name]:a}})
//output
[
    {
        "abc": {
            "name": "abc",
            "age": 15,
            "roll_no": 25
        }
    },
    {
        "def": {
            "name": "def",
            "age": 10,
            "roll_no": 20
        }
    },
    {
        "xyz": {
            "name": "xyz",
            "age": 16,
            "roll_no": 18
        }
    }
]
```